# Clojure default value with predicate

Tags: design-patterns, clojure

A common pattern is to provide a default value if some value does not fulfill a predicate. What is a good way of writing such a pattern when the value is *not* bound to a name?

Currently I use a let expression. If for example I would like to provide a default value for empty strings I might write something like:

```
(let [value {:a "foo"}]
  (if (:a value) value {:a "bar"}))
```

However, I feel like this could be simplified to closer match the same proceduce for falsy values.

```
(or value default)
```

I have considered creating a function that does it:

```
(defn or-default [pred value default]
  (if (pred value) value default))
```

With which the above example would become:

```
(or-default :a {:a "foo"} {:a "bar"})
```

However I assume someone must have thought about this earlier, so is there an established way?

Comment: I use `(or value default)`.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers my question was for some other predicate then simply truthy/falsy

Comment: that would be something you need: `(or (and (pred value) value) default)` if you want to avoid using `if`

Comment: i think  [merge](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge) `(merge {:a "bar"} {:a "foo"});;{:a "foo"}` does what you want

Answer (score 4):

You can use destructuring to solve this

```
(let [{:keys [a] :or {a "default"}} {:b "foo"}] a)
;; => default
```

Also, `get` lets you provide a default value:

```
(get :a {:b "foo"} "default")
;; => default
```

Also works with keyword access

```
 (:a {:b "foo"} "default")
 ;;=> default
```

Answer (score 2):

For supplying default values for map keys, the function you are looking for is essentially `merge` with the defaults as the first argument:

```
(merge {:a :a-default} {})
=> {:a :a-default}
(merge {:a :a-default} {:b 1})
=> {:a :a-default, :b 1}
(merge {:b 1, :a 2} {:a :a-default} {:b 1, :a 2})
=> {:b 1, :a 2}
```

We can package this as function `map-defaults` that, given the defaults, returns a function that fills them in:

```
(defn map-defaults [defaults]
  (partial merge defaults))
```

We can use this to create functions that perform particular defaults:

```
(def person-default 
  (map-defaults
    {:income 0
     :married false
     :forenames []}))

(person-default {})
=> {:income 0, :married false, :forenames []}

(person-default {:married true, :income 88000})
=> {:income 88000, :married true, :forenames []}
```

It is in the nature of defaults that they are used repeatedly, and the above is an easy way to do this.